# Java Spring WS Core with Maven POM

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-services, soap

I am using spring services in my java project and managing dependencies using maven pom. Something like this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <version>2.3.1-RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

The problem is that this by default uses SOAP V1.1 for communication.
Is it possible to make it use V1.2 by changing certain properties in the pom file? I am asking as I get an error like this:

```
Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; 
charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; 
charset=utf-8'
```

From what I understand that is happening because at my end the version of SOAP is V1.1(text/xml) and the other end wants V1.2 (application/soap+xml)
Also, is there any way to dynamically set the content type to 'text/xml' or 'application/soap+xml'? Or does it depend on the SOAP version and it cannot be configured dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what worked for me. If you dynamically want to change it in your code, you can do that using this:

```
MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAP_VERSION);
SaajSoapMessageFactory newSoapMessageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(msgFactory);
WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(newSoapMessageFactory);
```

and then you can use the SOAP functions as usual. So this way, you can parameterize this and use SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 depending on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can set the soap version on SaajSoapMessageFactory like below example, and set it for your WebServiceTemplate

```
<!-- Configure the SOAP version to 1.2 -->
<bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="myproject.wsdl.ws"/>

<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://my.web.service?wsdl"/>
</bean>
```

Courtesy - https://myshittycode.com/category/spring/spring-web-services/